# Locator Appearance

Tags: locator

I am using `LocatorPane` with `LocatorAutoCreate -> True`. **I would like to have the appearance of each new locator be different**. Ideally I would like to use a dot with a numeric superscript that would be incremented as they where created, but just using the incremented number as the locator would be good too. Is this possible?

Comment: Related: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/3313/5 (Eli and David's answers are especially relevant)

Comment: @rm-rf But those answers only deal with determining the appearance of *all* locators at the same time.

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries I just said that they're related (not dupes) and someone seeing this question might also find those interesting/relevant.

Comment: @rm-rf Fair enough. I only wanted to prevent trigger-happy closers from prematurely closing this.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I am not aware of any built-in option to do this, but using some graphics in combination with `Dynamic` does the trick.

```
pts = {{0, 0}};
LocatorPane[Dynamic[pts], 
  Graphics[
   {
     Circle[], 
     Dynamic@MapIndexed[Text[#2[[1]], #1 + {0.05, 0.05}] &, pts]
   }
  ], 
LocatorAutoCreate -> True]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

or, with `Appearance -> "\[CenterDot]"`:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: You sir are a hero. Great answer! Thank you very much.